# What is the kubectl equivalent commands to "minikube service <service name>"?

Tags: command, kubectl, minikube, equivalent

I have executed `minikube service mynginx1` and the result is:

```
 |-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------------------|
 | NAMESPACE |   NAME   | TARGET PORT |             URL             |
 |-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------------------| 
 | default   | mynginx1 | 8080-80     | http://192.168.85.153:31706 |
 |-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------------------|
```

What are the kubectl equivalent commands so that I can retrieve the URL if I am not using minikube?

Comment: I also created a service using kubectl on a master and two slave nodes and created the same mynginx1 service.  However, I can't connect to the "Welcome to Nginx" using the mater node's IP address and  NodePort 30980.  On Minikube I can.  I don't know what other steps to take.

Answer (score 4):

Port forward worked for me

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/es-manual 9200:9200
```

Answer (score 3):

To expose k8s application you can use [kubectl expose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose)
to create [service of type NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport):

```
kubectl expose pod <pod_name> --type NodePort --port 8080
```

or

```
kubectl expose deployment <deployment_name> --type NodePort --port 8080
```

then when you list your services you will see:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
<service_name> NodePort    10.99.147.24   <none>        8080:31208/TCP   3s
```

Notice two ports under PORT column: `8080:31208/TCP`. First is in-cluster port and the second is a node port. So now you can access your service with nodePort using: `<node-IP>:31208` from outside of a cluster.

There is another option which only applies of you are running in cloud environment and LoadBalancers are supported (so if you are either using k8s as a service solution or running self hosted k8s in cloud with cloud provider configured).
You can create a [service of type LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) like following:

```
kubectl expose pod <pod_name> --type LoadBalacer --port 8080
```

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
<service_name>   LoadBalancer   10.107.151.19   x.x.x.x       8080:31111/TCP   2s
```

and now use EXTERNAL-IP address to connect to your service: `x.x.x.x:8080`

Comment: Hi, I used the "kubectl expose deployment..." and got an 404 error.  At least its an improvement but I still don't get the "Welcome to Nginx" page.  I used the master node's IP address and the port is "31216".  That is http://<master node IP>:31216.

Comment: If you are receiving 404 from nginx then it's no longer kubernetes problem but nginx problem. Please check your nginx config. If you are having any nginx issues  you can post a new question on stackoverflow akings for this very specific problem.

Comment: What is the value of `<node-IP>` in your example where `<node-IP>:31208` is being used for a NodePort connection? The Cluster-IP doesn't work, and I think the IP would be something like 198.168.64.2 but I'm not sure where to get that value from

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the OP when trying to use Docker Desktop instead of Minikube - Docker desktop now comes with a Kubernetes single-node cluster so I didn't see the need to install Minikube in order to play with Kubernetes on my dev machine.

Assuming you use `kubectl get services` to list your services, you can then use `kubectl cluster-info` to get your master node ip.
OOTB, Docker Desktop sets `127.0.0.1` as the master node ip (or you could use `kubernetes.docker.internal`)

```
>> kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
helloworld   NodePort    10.107.197.207   <none>        80:32714/TCP   71m
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        3h4m
>> kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

With the above information I can launch `helloworld` at `http://kubernetes.docker.internal:32714/` or `http://127.0.0.1:32714/`

Answer (score 0):

equivalent to minikube service mynginx1
would be
kubectl get service mynginx1